# What do you need apart from registering IP addresses to use them?

Tags: ipv4

I need to connect to a certain Site from several public IP addresses (~1 million).

Assume that I am Bruce Wayne so I could spend several million dollars on this. The site at least for now is not IPv6 accessible which is a shame. I see that I can [register](https://www.arin.net/resources/fees/fee_schedule/) the right to use some IPv4 addresses from some companies for some time interval.

My question is, once I have done that, what do I need to do to actually be able to connect to this site via these IP addresses? I guess I have to setup a sort of minimalistic ISP but I want to know what exact sequence of actions is necessary (and preferably what are some ways to reduce the costs). A noob asking.

Comment: Announce theses IP via BGP to at least two others AS. Most probably, this is already done by the company that sells you theses IP if it is your ISP as well.

Comment: @Nakrule thank you! I thought of buying IPs from ARIN which is not an ISP I guess.

Comment: ARIN is the north america Regional Internet Registries (RIR), so the authority responsible for allocating IP addresses in your region. As it is not an ISP, you have to advertise your IP yourself via BGP. Note that an ISP can give you IP addresses as well (after receiving it from a RIR).

Comment: @Nakrule I see, I am just not sure about buying from ISP because I have pretty particular needs and do not want to pay too much. Are there ISP's that bill you for the total amount of traffic from all IP's you buy from them (because in my case, there is going to be around 5 Mb data exchange through every IP address)?

Comment: @Nakrule you can also ask your ISP to announce the IP block you've purchased from your RIR, this is what we do. They've just supplied us their public AS and that is then configured on the RIR web portal. After that it's up to the ISP to do "all the magic".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry Batman, but ARIN has no more IPv4 addresses to give you.  And even if they did, they only allocate blocks of addresses.  If you can't justify why you need a block of addresses (as opposed to one or two) they will direct you to an ISP instead.

To quote from [their website](https://www.arin.net/resources/guide/ipv4/):

> ARIN’s free pool of IPv4 address space was depleted on 24 September
>   2015. As a result, we no longer can fulfill requests for IPv4 addresses unless you meet certain policy requirements that reserved
>   blocks of IPv4 addresses for special cases.

Instead of pretending you're Bruce Wayne, pretend you're Jeff Bezos (He's richer).  You can set up a scalable, reliable, global computing infrastructure with high speed access.  AWS (or their competitors) can provide everything you need, including IP addresses.

To answer your specific question:

> Once I have done that, what do I need to do to actually be able to
>   connect to this site via these IP addresses?

Assuming you acquire the address space you want, you will connect your network to one or more ISPs.  You will advertise your addresses to the ISPs via BGP, who will in turn advertise them to the rest of the Internet.

Comment: can you clarify what does "you can't justify" mean? Like, I am supposed to give them a reason or something?

Comment: More than that.  You need to explain to them why you need a block of 256 addresses (for example) and how you will allocate them in your network.  You can't just write them a check and expect to get addresses.

Comment: Large blocks of IP addresses are available on the secondary market for around $20 per.  ~ 1 million  is too big for that market too.

Comment: regarding the second part, I suppose if I want to use all these addresses myself, I will also have to pay to the ISP's I have advertisted to, right? Is there a way to avoid that? Like, buy my own hardware (whatever is necessary) so that I can actually connect from my laptop?

Comment: You pay your ISP for connectivity to the Internet, not for advertising addresses.  I would assume a business account would assume you're running BGP with them.

Comment: thank you. the thing I do not quite understand is how would price formation work under such circumstances. Suppose I need to transmit 5 mb data from each IP, and we have 1 million of IPs, that would make 5 Tb data. Would the company charge me the price of 1 million standard plans or can a better deal be worked out (by which I mean were there such deals in the past)?